# I'm trying to load PDF(over 2MB) from a uri with barteksc Android Viewer, but it doesn't work

Tags: android, pdf, viewer

I started this from simple example and here's the code.

I tested several pdf documents from url but I could see only blank spaces on my mobile screeen.

Those pdf documents was opened in the browsers though...

so am I missing something?

please get me some advices...

thanks in advance!!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PDFView pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
    pdfView.fromUri(Uri.parse("http://xxxxxx/xxx.pdf"))
            .enableSwipe(true)
            .enableDoubletap(true)
            .swipeVertical(false)
            .defaultPage(1)
            .showMinimap(false)
            .enableAnnotationRendering(false)
            .password(null)
            .showPageWithAnimation(true)
            .load();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The library cant load from Http, you need download file and load from local Uri.

And remember you need `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for download and read file.

As per android official [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/usage-notes) :

> Android 6.0 Marshmallow introduced a new permissions model that lets
>   apps request permissions from the user at runtime, rather than prior
>   to installation. Apps that support the new model request permissions
>   when the app actually requires the services or data protected by the
>   services.